# Use jQuery draggable and resizable to draw elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to figure out how to draw a div using the draggable and resizable jQuery libraries. I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7bJak/2/)
Which is pretty nice but I really want this functionality to work with the mentioned libraries. To be more specific I want to be able to create a draggable element and drag(resize) it all in one shot. Is this possible?

EDIT: Perhaps I need to do something when the 'create' event happens in draggable or resizable? Do I need to somehow put my mouse on the resizable corner thingy? resizable doesn't seem to turn on until you actually lift your mouse and then press and drag on the resize corner. Here's the code I have now:

```
 $('.container').live('mousedown', function(){
    $('.container').append('<div class="gen-box"></div>');
    $('.gen-box').resizable().draggable();
 });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19768036/1300910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. I used selectable() as per @lunchmeat317's suggestion. I was able to capture the mouse positions during selectable's events: 'start' and 'stop' create a div with the right width and height and position. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XELRX/1/)

Comment: BTW, with this method you need to watch out for which direction the mouse is dragging to and add extra logic. In the fiddle, you can drag the mouse right or left and it will make a div, but dragging upward won't work because there is no logic for it(yet).

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this differently - I would use something like the jQueryUI [`selectable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) component, which already provides the boxing method. It has `start` and `stop` events which expose the mouse coordinates. Based on that, you can create a div on the `stop` event with the required mouse coordinates, and then add resizable and draggable to that div.

That's how I'd do it, anyway.

Your other option would be to do exactly what you're doing, and try using jQuery [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), like so:

```
 $('.container').live('mousedown', function(){
    $('.container').append('<div class="gen-box"></div>');
    $('.gen-box').resizable().draggable();
    $('.gen-box').trigger('mousedown'); // This may activate the resize ability, but you may need to target the resize handle, instead of the full div.
 });
```

This seems like it should work, but there may be some issues (I ran into a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/jquery-ui/O7Fbla-FGwU/TNIqvEj1_9cJ) from 2008). This might help put you on the right path, though. Good luck.

Comment: I think you are right. Selectable does look promising. I am playing with it now but I still can't figure it ou :\

Answer (score 0):

Dragging and resizable div's can be easy made with the [jquery ui library](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

You could try this example. Download the latest JQuery and JQuery ui libs and adjust the source paths in the example. For resizing you can use the resize function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {        
        $( '#test' ).draggable();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="test" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: red;" >
      <p>Drag me</p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Jvd. However this is not issue I am having. I need to be able to sort of "drag create" these instead of them appearing when the document is ready. Do you know how that could be done?

Comment: Do you want the div hidden when the page starts, and show it on a certain event?

Comment: No, i would like to create it dynamically, for example via something like the append() function.